# Job offer and planned vacation

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, negotiation, vacation, start-date

I got an interview for an amazing position that would be a huge advancement within my career (only 24). I have recently booked a trip for a month and a half (leaving Feb coming back mid-march).

If I get accepted for the position, I will bring up my booked vacation - is there a possibility that they will give me the time off or extend the start date to mid-march (6 months away.

If they don't and give me an ultimatum would you take the job or an already booked\planned trip of a life time.

Comment: Depends how much you value your career.Personally I'd take the trip because I'm an old man and I sacrificed way to much 'fun' when I was younger and regret some of it. Life and travel experience versus work experience.....

Comment: Are you willing to take the 6 weeks without pay?

Comment: If it's "an amazing position that would be a huge advancement" then you can always take that job, put money aside every month, and have a "trip of a life time" whenever that job finishes.

Comment: Of course there is a possibility. How much of one , not they can tell you. Ask. It may be fine, or it may not be, depending on how immediately they need you.  If they say no, you will have to pick your priorities.

Comment: The last part of your question "What would you do?" is not appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my story. It's a little long, but similar to yours. Please bear with me.

---

I was 21 doing final semester at college studying Economics. But I was into UX design and applied for a position at a startup in February. I would be graduating in May.

I was called for an interview. I was so happy that they liked my work, but at the same time worried sick if they would take me seriously(Economics student).

I travelled to Bangalore from Hyderabad for the interview.
**During the interview, they asked the inevitable question as to when I could join if I was given an offer.**

> I had already planned a 15 day road trip with my closest friends. I
>   knew it would be the last time we would all be together before we set
>   off on our own paths. We had planned it for months.

I gave them a date and explained: college ends on May 15th + 15days trip + 5 days buffer. I told them, that I could join from 5th of June.

The interview continued for a few more minutes before they dropped the bomb. **They cannot hire me cause they require complete dedication from team members and everyone has to make sacrifices. They wanted me to cancel my trip.** They moved onto another topic expecting me to comply.

I interrupted the interviewer(CTO) and told him: ***There is no point in continuing the interview when you're not interested in respecting a decision that I made prior to applying for a position with your company. The trip means a lot to me, and I cannot cancel it.*** We said our goodbyes and I left.

Since I had until evening to catch my bus home I walked to the nearest restaurant. Just when I was about to enter, the CTO called me on my mobile(approximately 20mins after I left). He wanted me to come back to their office and discuss.

I was hungry, so I told him I was out eating and couldn't come by for another hour. I took my time and went back. **They had an offer for me. And yes, they were okay with my trip.**

> On a later date I realised that they must've tested me. What would I
>   do? Would I change my plans/decisions just because someone is forcing
>   me to?

---

I'm not sure if my story helps you in taking the right step forward, but I wish you the best. Cheers!

Comment: Very cool story. I think than rather than testing you they were just bluffing - if they could have you without trip, the better. That's quite evil from their regard actually.

Comment: I had accepted the offer and joined them as an intern(remote) until college ended. Sadly during that short period I was made to do work other than what I was hired for. I ended up not joining them.

Answer (score 2):

Bring it up after you have an offer but before you accept, they may or may not allow you to take it and they may or may not pay you for it since you may not have accumulated that much vacation by then. It is highly unlikely they would delay your start date by months.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing something you haven't got - a job offer from this company - with something you have - a vacation.

Worry about it once you have a job offer.

Answer (score 0):

> If they don't and give me an ultimatum would you take the job or an already booked\planned trip of a life time.

I'd go on the trip and let whatever happens happen regarding the job without worrying about it or letting it spoil my plans.

Travelling is best done young and carefree before life ties you down and a simple trip to the beach entails a whole bunch of logistics like nappies, route, sandwich making with two loaves of bread, making sure there's enough towels, watching over others safety etc,.